# Whether the cpu scheduling is based on processes or threads in linux?

Tags: cpu, scheduling

In some text books, there is chapter which is named as "process scheduling". In such chapter it talks about cpu scheduling. While in many articles, they use threads scheduling to refer to cpu scheduling. 
I know the concepts of process and thread is different. I am confused that what cpu scheduler actually operates on, threads or processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially based on quantum which is an amount of basic unit of time the thread will execute for. Also I believe there is a priority level so multiple threads are competing for time on the cpu. They wait in line with other threads of same priority level and then run till they are out of quantum. Then they are sent to the back. It's not exact answer but a high level summary.

Also I'm more familar with windows but I think it is same in principles. The process is not an executable code but a unit of storage. So it would be by thread. Linux I read has a more complicated scheduling algorithm than windows (more overhead possibly as a trade off), but it is completely possible I speculate that threads of same process compete for cpu time. The difference is there is no necessary context switch cause the thread sharing process use same address space.

This would explain the diminished returns when using more threads than the physical number of cores(threads on intel). The threads of a process have a small chance of ever running at the same time. Instead they compete. So if you have 4000 threads it means the time any single one of them is running is reduced by 1/4000. However if you were to use the 4000 threads to operate on a single synchronous problem, using a shared storage to load current state you could then get performance gain by having a larger percentage of cpu time as the probability of any of the 4000 threads running is higher.

Comment: Also the o.s. Probably isn't intended to be used in this mannor and may even prevent a process from diluting other threads. Also interrupts and threads which finish execution will invoke the scheduling algorithm, perhaps short of the current threads quantum limit. In some o.s. It gets to roll over it's quantum.